# How to create a pandas dataframe that contains ordered lists based on analysis conditions applied on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I working on a Python project that have a dataframe like this:

```
col = {
        'ID': ['123.abc', '123.abc', '123.abc', '456.efg', '456.efg', '123.abc', '123.abc', '789.hij'],
        'Content': ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'BBB', 'DDD', 'AAA', 'CCC', 'AAA'],
        'Visit sequence': ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '1', '2', '1'],
        'Value': ['0', '0', '5.21', '0', '9.74', '0', '0', '3.83']}
df = pd.DataFrame(col)
```

which leads to the following data table:

| **ID** | **Content** | **Visit sequence** | **Value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123.abc | AAA | 1 | 0 |
| 123.abc | BBB | 2 | 0 |
| 123.abc | CCC | 3 | 5.21 |
| 456.efg | BBB | 1 | 0 |
| 456.efg | DDD | 2 | 9.74 |
| 123.abc | AAA | 1 | 0 |
| 123.abc | CCC | 2 | 0 |
| 789.hij | AAA | 1 | 3.83 |

The task consists of generating the following dataframe:

| **ID** | **Journey** | **Value** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123.abc | AAA, BBB, CCC | 5 |
| 123.abc | AAA, CCC | 0 |
| 456.efg | BBB, DDD | 4 |
| 789.hij | AAA | 1 |

where the `Journey` column contains a list of `Contents` found until getting an amount in `Value` column. Is also considered the journey of contents that do not find amounts in the `Value` column, as you can see for the case of `ID` 123.abc.

Could you help me by suggesting a code that solves this task? I kind of got a solution for this task, but since I used a lot of loop functions, I can't apply the algorithm to a larger database because the time processing is too high.

Comment: How is the value column generated in the output?

Comment: Group by ID; sort groups by Sequence; filter groups for indices <= first non-zero in Value; concatenate Content of the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groupoing by 'ID' and by the cumsum of the non-0 'Value's does the trick:

```
df2 = (df.groupby([df['ID'], ((df['Value']!='0').shift().fillna(0)).cumsum()], as_index=False)
    .agg({'Content' : ','.join, 'Value':'last'})
)
```

output:

```
    ID       Content        Value
--  -------  -----------  -------
 0  123.abc  AAA,BBB,CCC     5.21
 1  123.abc  AAA,CCC         0
 2  456.efg  BBB,DDD         9.74
 3  789.hij  AAA             3.83
```

Comment: Great solution, I checked it with `%%timeit` and your way to go is about 25% faster. *upvote* PS: the only thing that is missing is the Name "Journey" instead of "Content"

Comment: @Marco_CH I guess this is from avoiding adding a new column for groupby, which indeed is not necessary for groupby to work. Appreciate the upvote but since performance is not the point of the question, and functionally the two are identical, let's even the field

Comment: It worked! Thank you @piterbarg for the solution

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, the value column is not clear to me, but I'll provide my solution, where only the final calculation for this column is missing/not correct. Maybe it's something simple that you can easily adapt:

```
i = df.ID    
df["group"] = i.ne(i.shift()).cumsum()
df2 = df[["ID", "group","Content", "Value"]].groupby(["ID", "group"]). \
    agg({'Content' : ','.join, 
         "Value":"last"}).reset_index()

df2 = df2.rename(columns={"Content":"Journey"}).drop("group", axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
    ID              Journey         Value
0   123.abc         AAA,BBB,CCC     5.21
1   123.abc         AAA,CCC         0
2   456.efg         BBB,DDD         9.74
3   789.hij         AAA             3.83
```